# Using multiple rows and spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow

I would like to preface this by saying that my experience with LaTeX is very limited. I have read the documentation but is pretty difficult for me to understand.

My table is the following:

[image]

Few things here. As you can see my column spacing is very off when it comes to the values and they do not align with the column headers. I have figured that I need to use `\multiplerows{}` perhaps to fix this. Is this the right path? How would I implement that`

Also, the spacing in-between each new entry is ok but also on the large side. Is there a one line code that I could implement to bump the spacing down a little bit from what I am guessing is the default setting?

Here is my code (adapted from a template online):

```
\begin{document}

\begin{slide*}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Breakdown by Voivodeship}
    \label{tab:kathoden}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}nd{1.1}*{4}{d{1.2}}d{1.1}d{3.2}@{}}
      \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{\bf{Voivodeship}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Total Cases} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Cases 100k} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Total Deaths} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Deaths 100k} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Total Tests} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Total Tests} &
        \multicolumn{1}{N}{Case Fatality} \\
        
      \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}%
        \cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}
        
        Lower Silesia & 1100  & 1.15 & 1.25 & 1.45 & 1 & 220 & 20 \\
        Kuyavian-Pomeranian & 1.5 & 1.8  & 1.9  & 2.2  & 1.5 & 20 & 20 \\
        Lublin   & 2   & 2.3  & 2.5  & 2.9  & 2 & 20 & 20 \\
        Lubusz & 3   & 2.9  & 3.1  & 3.6  & 2.5 & 20 & 20 \\
        Lodz   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 10.8  & 4.3  & 20 & 20 & 20 \\
        Lesser Poland   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3 & 20 & 20 & 29\\
        Mazowieckie   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Opole   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Subcarpathian   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Podlasie   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Pomorskie   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Silesian   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Pomorskie   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Pomorskie   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Pomorskie   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
        Silesian   & 3.5 & 3.5  & 3.8  & 4.3  & 3   & 264.$---$ \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{slide*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of what you have tried so far for us to work on.

Comment: Has been edited

Comment: How are the `n` and `N` column types defined? Which document class do you use?

Comment: Please consider reading [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal working example (MWE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to the world of LaTeX tables, I will give you my recipe.

First, LaTeX is for producing beautiful print materials or slides. For actual work with numbers, I use excel.
(Other people will use R or some other statistics package.)

While in the spreadsheet  you can do calculations, reorder columns, put color in titles or cells, set the lines, etc. until you get the final result, according to your  taste or the original you are reproducing  or the style that you must comply with for a final report or thesis.

[image]

Then you go to LaTeX. You can manually enter the table cell by cell, row by row, or export it from its source (strongly recommended).

I use an Excel add-in excel2latex that produces (almost) the final code. The most important part is that it will faithfully export the content, so nothing is lost in translation.

https://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex?lang=en

[image]

Copy to clipboard and paste it into your LateX code. It will compile without errors. (In this case you need to add the  package `booktabs`).

Then you can work with the too-many LaTex packages dedicated to tables to fit the table to the page, change the style, etc. But most importantly, the original content will remain intact!

For this example, I added the shorter column rules and the caption (cut and paste from original). Other embellishments remains for the reader. :)

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} %required
\usepackage{multirow} %not needed here but useful
\usepackage{geometry} % to fit the table in the page

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
 \caption{Breakdown by Voivodeship}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Voivodeship} & Total Cases & Cases 100k & Total Deaths & Deaths 100k & Total Tests & Total Tests & Case Fatality \\
         \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}%
        \cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}
%       \midrule
        Lower Silesia & 1100  & 1.15  & 1.25  & 1.45  & 1     & 220   & 20 \\
        Kuyavian-Pomeranian & 1.5   & 1.8   & 1.9   & 2.2   & 1.5   & 20    & 20 \\
        Lublin & 2     & 2.3   & 2.5   & 2.9   & 2     & 20    & 20 \\
        Lubusz & 3     & 2.9   & 3.1   & 3.6   & 2.5   & 20    & 20 \\
        Lodz  & 3.5   & 3.5   & 10.8  & 4.3   & 20    & 20    & 20 \\
        Lesser Poland & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 20    & 20    & 29 \\
        Mazowieckie & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Opole & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Subcarpathian & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Podlasie & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Pomorskie & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Silesian & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Pomorskie & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Pomorskie & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Pomorskie & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        Silesian & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   & 3     & 264   & --- \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would write your table directly in LaTeX.

Using `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package, left calculation of `\tabcolsep` to macro `\extracolsep{\fill}}`, for column headers use `\thead` command defined in the `makecell` package. That table can be fit in slide, for font size is used `\scriptsize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\scriptsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My beautiful table}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Breakdown by Voivodeship}
\label{tab:kathoden}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l 
                                S[table-format=4.1] 
                                S[table-format=1.2]
                                S[table-format=2.2]
                                S[table-format=1.2]
                                S[table-format=2.1]
                                S[table-format=3.0]
                                S[table-format=2.0]
                                }
      \toprule
\thead{Voivodeship}
    &   {\thead{Total\\ Cases}} 
        &   {\thead{\\Cases\\ 100k}}
            &   {\thead{Total\\ Deaths}}
                &   {\thead{Deaths \\100k}}
                    &   {\thead{Total\\ Tests}}
                        &   {\thead{Total\\ Tests}}
                            &   {\thead{Case\\ Fatality}} \\
    \midrule
%      \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}%
%        \cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}

Lower Silesia 
    & 1100  & 1.15  &  1.25 & 1.45  & 1     & 220   & 20    \\
Kuyavian-Pomeranian 
    & 1.5   & 1.8   &  1.9  & 2.2   & 1.5   & 20    & 20    \\
Lublin   
    & 2     & 2.3   &  2.5  & 2.9   & 2     & 20    & 20    \\
Lubusz 
    & 3     & 2.9   &  3.1  & 3.6   & 2.5   & 20    & 20    \\
Lodz   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   & 10.8  & 4.3   & 20    & 20    & 20    \\
Lesser Poland  
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   & 20    & 20    & 29    \\
Mazowieckie   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Opole  
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Subcarpathian   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Podlasie    
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Pomorskie  
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Silesian   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    &  264  & {---} \\
Pomorskie  
    & 3.5   & 3.5   &  3.8  & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Pomorskie   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8    & 4.3  &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Pomorskie   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8    & 4.3  &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
Silesian   
    & 3.5   & 3.5   & 3.8   & 4.3   &  3    & 264   & {---} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]